# Wrap sqlalchemy's filter and filter_by functions in a single function

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to wrap the functions filter and filter_by into a single function
and call filter or filter_by based on the parameters.

The function must behave in a way that these two would return the same thing:

```
MyModel.get(MyModel.mycolumn == 'value')
MyModel.get(mycolumn='value')
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it based on whether the arguments are given as keywords or not:

```
def get(*args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs:
        return query.filter_by(**kwargs)
    else:
        return query.filter(*args)
```

Comment: I'm stupid. I was trying to do it by using only **kwargs... thnx!

Comment: even better might be `return query.filter(*args).filter_by(**kwargs)` so you can pass both!